# ¿Como mover varios tipos de archivos desde un directorio inferior a un directorio superior sin la necesidad de estar en la ubicación de los archivos?

Tags: bash, terminal

quería mover todos los archivos .txt desde una SubSubCarpeta (/**Carpeta**/SubCarpeta/SubSubCarpeta) hacia su **Carpeta** padre parece algo simple pero el problema es que las SubSubCarpetas son más de 10 por eso me preguntaba si se podía mover los archivo .txt sin la necesidad de entrar a todas las SubSubCarpetas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas usando Unix? si es asi, puedes utilizar este comando desde `/Carpeta/SubCarpeta/SubSubCarpeta`:

```
mv *.txt ../../../Carpeta/
```

Prueba:

Creo un ambiente similar al tuyo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, ejecuto el comando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por ultimo, vuelvo a la carpeta raiz y muestro el contenido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota:** debes tener en cuenta que los archivos seran movidos, es decir ya no existiran en `/Carpeta/SubCarpeta/SubSubCarpeta`. Si quieres preservar los archivos tanto en `/Carpeta/SubCarpeta/SubSubCarpeta` como en `/Carpeta`, debes cambiar el `mv` por `cp`, asi:

```
cp *.txt ../../../Carpeta/
```

Comment: ¿ Y puedo mover los archivos .txt de la SubSubCarpeta estando en esta ubicación /home/luisfelipe/Carpeta ?

Comment: @ANONIMO69: claro, solo debes indicar las rutas: ```mv SubCarpeta/SubSubCarpeta/*.txt .``` (nota que hay un punto al final, esto significa 'a esta misma carpeta')

Comment: @ANONIMO69, pero ```home/luisfelipe``` es la carpeta de mi maquina, no de la tuya. Si gustas mas ayuda, abre tu consola de linux y escribe ```pwd``` en tu carpeta home y luego ```pwd``` en tu carpeta SubSubCarpeta

Comment: Si, se que es tu maquina pero me preguntaba si se podia mover los archivos .txt desde la ubicación de la Carpeta Padre!

Comment: Sí se puede, solo ejecuta desde ```Carpeta``` este comando: ```mv SubCarpeta/SubSubCarpeta/*.txt .```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: @ANONIMO69 si la respuesta te sirve, no olvides marcarla como correcta (es el simbolo de check ✅que sale al lado de la respuesta, casi al inicio del texto )